# What the difference between pin and pn diodes i-v curve?

Tags: diodes, semiconductors, pn-junction

For my understanding there should be no big difference in i-v curve between regular p-n junction and p-i-n junction, the only difference i can think about is do to the bigger resistance of the intrinsic layer. The curve should look the same only the current will rise little bit slower, because of the resistance.
Am i right?

Comment: Have you tried, like, looking at some?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XpYsCM_Wf50

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is indeed no big difference in IV-curve between a PIN-diode and a regular abutted PN-diode when **forward biased**. For wider I-regions, the current may differ slightly.

I believe the statement

> the bigger resistance of the intrinsic layer

is incorrect though.

The resistivity \$\rho\$ tells us how charges move under the influence of an electric field, or

$$\vec{J} = \sigma \vec{E} = \frac{1}{\rho} \vec{E}$$

This method of carrier transport is called *drift*. However, diode operation also heavily depends on *diffusion*. The higher resistivity basically causes the depletion region to be wider as the balance between drift and diffusion tilts more towards diffusion.

PN-diode current increases as more charges have enough energy to cross the built-in potential barrier. Applying a voltage will lower that potential barrier, causing more electrons to to cross it increasing the current.

A PIN-diode has a barrier height that is the same as for a PN-diode with the same doping concentrations for P and N-regions. A PIN-diode, however, will have a barrier spread out over a longer distance. This may effect the IV-curve, but from what I have found in simulations that effect is rather small.

Other more notable differences:

- A PIN-diode has a wider depletion region, so it also has a lower capacitance.
- The electric field is also weaker in a PIN diode due the wider depletion region. This means that the breakdown voltage will be larger too.

Answer (score -1):

Major **structural difference** between PIN diode when compared to a signal diode is the **lightly doped N- layer** in PIN diode.

Comment: I think OP knew that. OP is not refering to the general difference between PIN and PN, but specific, with respect to the i-v curve